# Plot of phonon-drag thermopower in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I am interested in the phonon-drag thermopower in the case of bilayer graphene. I am following the paper "https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.82.155410". In this paper, I want to plot sg (eq. 3) with temperature (T). In Mathematica, it shows the recursion limit error. Here I am attaching the Mathematica code. Kindly have a look and suggest where I am making mistakes. I will be thankful to you for this.

```
m = 0.033*9.108*10^-31;(*Effective mass (kg) of electron in BLG*)
d1 = 6.8*1.6*10^-19;(*Deformation potential coupling constant (J)*)
\[Lambda] = 8.8*10^-6;(*Phonon mean free path (m)*)
ns = 0.79*10^16;(*electron density (m^-2)in BLG *)
hbar = 1.054571817*10^-34; (*Planck constant in Js*)
e = 1.602*10^-19;(*Charge on electron in Coulomb*)
kb = 1.380649*10^-23;(*Boltzmann constant in J/K*)
\[Rho] = 3.67*10^-7;(*density of BLG in Kg/m^2*)
vs = 2*10^4; (* velocity of acoustic phonon in m/s*)
kf = (Pi*ns)^(1/2);(*Fermi wave vector*)
ef = (hbar*kf)^2/(2*m);
q[\[Omega]_] := \[Omega]/vs; (*Phonon wave vector*)
nq[\[Omega]_, 
   T_] := (Exp[hbar*\[Omega]/(kb*T)] - 
    1)^-1; (*Phonon Bose distribution function*)
fi[ek_, T_] := (Exp[(ek - ef)/(kb*T)] + 1)^-1
ff[ek_, T_, \[Omega]_] := (Exp[(ek + hbar*\[Omega] - ef)/(kb*T)] + 
    1)^-1;
eq[\[Omega]_] := ((hbar)^2/(2*m))*((\[Omega]/(2*vs)) - (m*
       vs/hbar))^2;
g[ek_, \[Omega]_] := (1 - (hbar*\[Omega])^2/(4*m*vs*ek))^2;
sg[T_] := -(m^(3/2)*
     d1^2*\[Lambda] /(2^(3/2)*ns*e*kb*
        T^2*\[Rho]*(Pi)^2*(hbar*vs)^4))*\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(hbar*
\*SuperscriptBox[\((hbar*\[Omega])\), \(3\)]*\((
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(eq\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\((g[
          ek, \[Omega]]*nq[\[Omega], T]*fi[ek, T]*
         ff[ek, T, \[Omega]]/
          Sqrt[ek - 
            eq[\[Omega]]])\) \[DifferentialD]ek)\) \[DifferentialD]\
\[Omega]\)\)
ds = Plot[-sg[T], {T, 30, 70}]
```

Comment: Do you want the lower limit of your integral to be eq[omega]?  You have eq currently.

Comment: You may want to scale out (i.e, non-dimensionalize) the units in your problem.  You are multiplying very large numbers by very small ones and that may give you numerical inaccuracy.

Comment: Yes lower limit is eq, which is also a function of Omega.

Comment: The behaviour of graph is plotted in fig 2 of  the given ref.

Comment: You will need to make the lower limit of your integrand eq[omega], currently you have only eq.

Comment: I think you will need to resort to numerical integration.  I set  your constants = 1 (you can do something similar by introducing, say, a temperature and ek that have units of omega^2).  Then  a numerical integration of the inside integral via `integrand[ek_, \[Omega]_, 
  T_] := (g[ek, \[Omega]]*nq[\[Omega], T]*fi[ek, T]*
   ff[ek, T, \[Omega]]/Sqrt[ek - eq[\[Omega]]])` and `integral[\[Omega]_, T_] := 
 With[{integrand = integrand[ek, \[Omega], T], ll = eq[\[Omega]]},
  NIntegrate[integrand, {ek, ll, Infinity}]]` and then `integral[1, 2]`.  And then integrate again over your T of interest