# Mathematica is not showing the plot

Tags: plotting

Kindly take a look at this code. Mathematica is not evaluating the integration. Here I am providing the code. Please help me plot this integral.

```
m = 0.033*9.108*10^-31;(*Effective mass (kg) of electron in BLG*)
d1 = 6.8*1.6*10^-19;(*Deformation potential coupling constant (J)*)
\[Lambda] = 8.8*10^-6;(*Phonon mean free path (m)*)
ns = 0.79*10^16;(*electron density (m^-2)in BLG *)
hbar = 1.054571817*10^-34; (*Planck constant in Js*)
e = 1.602*10^-19;(*Charge on electron in Coulomb*)
kb = 1.380649*10^-23;(*Boltzmann constant in J/K*)
\[Rho] = 3.67*10^-7;(*density of BLG in Kg/m^2*)
vs = 2*10^4; (* velocity of acoustic phonon in m/s*)
kf = (Pi*ns)^(1/2);(*Fermi wave vector*)
ef = (hbar*kf)^2/(2*m);
q = \[Omega]/vs; (*Phonon wave vector*)
eq = ((hbar)^2/(2*m))*((\[Omega]/(2*vs)) - (m*vs/hbar))^2;
nq = (Exp[hbar*\[Omega]/(kb*t)] - 
    1)^-1; (*Phonon Bose distribution function*)
fi = (Exp[(ek - ef)/(kb*t)] + 1)^-1;
ff = (Exp[(ek + hbar*\[Omega] - ef)/(kb*t)] + 1)^-1;
g = (1 - (hbar*\[Omega])^2/(4*m*vs*ek))^2;
inti = Integrate[(g*nq*fi*(1 - ff))/(ek - eq)^0.5, ek];
upper = Limit[inti, ek -> \[Infinity]];
lower = Limit[inti, ek -> eq];
int1 = Evaluate[upper - lower];
intf = Integrate[hbar^4*\[Omega]^3*int1, \[Omega]];
upper2 = Limit[intf, \[Omega] -> 0];
lower2 = Limit[intf, \[Omega] -> \[Infinity]];
int2 = Evaluate[upper2 - lower2];
sg = -(((m^(3/2))*(d1^2)*\[Lambda] )/(
     2^(3/2)*ns*e*kb*t^2*\[Rho]*(Pi)^2*(hbar*vs)^4))*int2;
ds = Plot[-sg, {t, 0.5, 10}]
```

Comment: replace plot by Plot1 and look at its first argument?

Comment: In my case your code is crashing the kernel !

Comment: In my case too, its crashing the kernel

Comment: Sir can you share your email id

Comment: `(ek - eq)^0.5` should be `Sqrt[ek - eq]` or `(ek - eq)^(1/2)`. Machine-precision numbers like `0.5` are not the same as exact rationals like `1/2`.

Comment: What you're trying to plot is a number times `1/t^2`. And the only thing in that number that's suspect is `int2`. This isn't a problem with plot, it's a problem with your integrals. `intf` seems to be where it goes off the rails - you should investigate the argument.

Comment: @sandeepKumar it should not crash the kernel: that's a bug.

Comment: Didn’t you post the same question yesterday? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285846/plot-of-phonon-drag-thermopower-in-mathematica?noredirect=1#comment711671_285846

Comment: `upper` evaluates to `ConditionalExpression[0., Element[E^((344*\[Omega])/(45036596687279*t)) | \[Omega]^2 | \[Omega], Reals] && t > 0]`.  Before proceeding beyond this point, tell Mathematica whether the condition is satisfied, probably by using `FullSimplify`.  Or, set `upper` to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

It's failing on the `Integrate`, not the `Plot`. It's good practice to evaluate the lines one by one while looking for the source of a problem.

The `Integrate` fails because the expression encounters a divide-by-zero when either `t=0` or `\[Omega]=0`.

So the issue is how you are specifying the problem. Maybe you need to specify some integration limits, or include some assumptions in your Limit expressions.

Comment: Thank all for their valuable suggestion